# WooCommerce Change Subtotal String on Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I change the Subtotal text on the WooCommerce product page (not the cart page). Screenshot attached, I'd like to change 'Subtotal' > 'Subtotal (GST Inclusive)'

[Screenshot of Subtotal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9kr0.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In regular single product page of Woocommerce with default themes (like twentytwenty), there is no Subtotal inside it.

I believe, in your case, the Subtotal is shown by a plugin or theme function. So, you need to check the custom code that shows this Subtotal area. After making some research, please provide us your work related to issue and make clear your question.

Additionally, you can use translate plugins or plugin named String Locator to easily solve this issue.